# Use a View Model in MVC but retain protection against overposting attacks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to post back (and validate) two models in the same form so I have created a simple "view model" as suggested [here](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/multiple-viewmodels-in-a-single-mvc-view/) which contains both models.

This works, but I am unable to use the `Bind(Include="property")` attribute to bind the post-data to my `Entrant` object, and thus prevent overposting.

In the example below, `CodeWord` is bound correctly (as you would expect), but `Entrant.Name` is not.

**Model:**

```
public class EnterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public Entrant Entrant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CodeWord { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(
    [Bind(Include = "Entrant.Name,<etc.>,CodeWord")] EnterViewModel postedEntry)
{
  // Magic happens here
}
```

I could, of course, work around this by creating a new instance of `Entrant` after postback and only use the values that I want, but this seems inefficient when MVC has already created all of the objects that I need.

Comment: You not using a true view model. A view model contains only properties that you want to display/edit (i.e it would contain each property from `Entrant` in the view model (not an instance of `Entrant`). Using the `Bind` attribute should never be necessary when using a view model.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, although it is far from DRY - I have to duplicate most of my `Entrant` model and then manually map properties in the controller. It answer's my question though, so if you turn your comment into an answer I'll certainly accept it!